# Attach a UIView to a UIViewController programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

What is the best way of having a block of screen run by it's own view controller, whilst the rest of the app runs as normal, switching between views etc.

So the block of screen would be a permanent fixture (tho could be hidden), while the user can switch between tab, push new views etc?

Is there a way to programmatically attach a view to a view controller to do this, or is there some other method?

```
-----------------------------------------
|                                       |
|           nav bar or tool bar         |
-----------------------------------------
|                                       |
|                                       |
-----------------------------------------
|view to be attached to view controller | < this block stays even when in other views
-----------------------------------------
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|           main bit of the view        |
|          changes according to tab     |
|                                       |
|                                       |
|                                       |
-----------------------------------------
|       |       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |       | < tab bar
|       |       |       |       |       |
-----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of attaching to view controller, create the view in appDelegate or a singleton instance of the view and whenever a new view is pushed/switched, this view is moved to the front by writing

```
[self.view addSubview:_yourStaticView];
```

in the view did load methods of each view controller class. A single UIView controller has a stack, so it cannot render multiple views at the same time, it's either one or the other. Whenever you want to remove this view, write:

```
[_yourStaticView removeFromSuperview];
```

You can change the contents of this view just as you would with a UIView!